Oracle SQL query is failing on Oracle Cloud, but not on local Oracle/AWS databases. CAST CLOB
Our application is performing a query to update a value in a CLOB column, but the update needs to only be applied where the CLOB has an existing value. (I understand that this is not a great design paradigm, but it is a legacy application where column lengths have grown to support newer functionality)
This is the error that we get on an Oracle Cloud hosted version of Oracle 19c.
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 4423, maximum: 4000)

[Failed SQL: (22835) UPDATE Table1
SET Value = 'TEXT A'
WHERE DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Value) < 2000 AND CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(2000)) = 'TEXT B']

The SQL above was modified from a previous version where the test for LOB length was not present, and it failed when the CLOB column contained values greater than 2000 characters. This issue was reproducible locally, and adding the test for LOB length allowed this to work on our local versions of Oracle, and Oracle 19C hosted in AWS. It was tested locally with large values in the CLOB column (> 16k bytes)
However, a client has reported that the above query is failing on Oracle 19C hosted on Oracle Cloud. (They provided the output above)
Is there reason why this query would fail on different instances of Oracle. Is there a database configuration setting that would cause this query to not work?
We had also tried re-factoring the query, so that only CLOBs of less that 2000 chars would bubble up to the update query.. However the client says that this is still producing the same error as above.
UPDATE Table1
SET Value = 'TEXT A'
WHERE (Id1, Id2) IN (
    SELECT Id1, Id2
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM Table1
        WHERE DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Value) < 2000
    )
    WHERE CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(2000)) = 'TEXT B'
);

I haven't yet tested this on an Oracle Cloud instance of Oracle 19C yet.. but even if I can reproduce, I still need a way to address this.
Thanks. Appreciate any insight.

I eventually went with:
UPDATE Table1
SET Value = 'TEXT A'
WHERE DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(Value, 'TEST B') = 0

I actually found that this was already in some of our source code which I hadn't seen, and this is a little more concise than the other options given.
Appreciate your input though. Thanks.

SQL is not like procedural languages where you run the program line-by-line and each thing is done in sequence; the SQL engine can decide that it is more efficient to rewrite your query and push the predicates from the inner query to an outer query and then evaluate the predicates in a different order that it believes (based on its statistics) to be more efficient.
So your query is probably being rewritten as:
UPDATE Table1
SET Value = 'TEXT A'
WHERE (Id1, Id2) IN (
    SELECT Id1, Id2
    FROM   Table1
    WHERE  CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(2000)) = 'TEXT B'
    AND    DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Value) < 2000
);

If you want to ensure the inner query gets run without being written then (as per this answer or this answer) you can use:

the /*+ NO_MERGE */ hint or the (undocumented) /*+ materialize */ hint on the inner query;
the /*+ no_push_pred(subquery_alias) */ hint on the outer query; or
a ROWNUM filter.

Like this:
UPDATE Table1
SET Value = 'TEXT A'
WHERE (Id1, Id2) IN (
    SELECT Id1, Id2
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM Table1
        WHERE DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Value) < 2000
        AND   ROWNUM > 0
    )
    WHERE CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(2000)) = 'TEXT B'
);


However, you do not need the CAST and the length filter is redundant as anything that matches TEXT B will be less than 2000 bytes long so you can write the query as:
UPDATE Table1
SET Value = 'TEXT A'
WHERE (Id1, Id2) IN (
  SELECT Id1, Id2
  FROM   Table1
  WHERE  Value = 'TEXT B'
);

or:
MERGE INTO table1 dst
USING (
  SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 'TEXT B' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY id1, id2) AS cnt
  FROM   table1
) src
ON (src.cnt > 0 AND src.ROWID = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET value = 'TEXT A';


If the id1/id2 pair are unique then you can simplify the query even more to:
UPDATE Table1
SET   Value = 'TEXT A'
WHERE Value = 'TEXT B';


Cool.. Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll try some of those approaches.

Why not avoiding CAST by using
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (
   lob_loc     IN    CLOB   CHARACTER SET ANY_CS,
   amount      IN    INTEGER := 32767,
   offset      IN    INTEGER := 1)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 CHARACTER SET lob_loc%CHARSET;

so
   WHERE DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(Value, LENGTH('TEXT B')) = 'TEXT B' AND DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Value) = LENGTH('TEXT B')

?

Cool.. Thanks for the answer. I'll try that approach.
